# can android Google chrome be controlled as iOS Google Chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-chrome

I have an android application which strictly uses Google Chrome browser. When i had developed a similar app in iOS, I could control the way in which the tabs were opened. Pls check the link https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links. Now i am looking for similar functionality in Android Google Chrome. The iOS Chrome provides various classes to check if Google chrome is installed, prevent opening of a new tab, send a particular url to a tab, return control to the tab that opened the application, etc. It was really helpful during my application development. Can anyone suggest a similar functionality for android.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same but you should investigate the use of [Android Intents](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents).  Android is already designed around a system of launching tasks having them stacked and the user being able to press the back button to get back to the calling app or site.

You can't check if Chrome is installed but you can force a url to be opened in Chrome from an app using intents, and you can't stop it from opening a tab if the users chooses so, but intents get you to a place that is close.

Comment: i am sorry ... i  dont get you?